# AWS: run a process (with python fabric)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Simple question: I'm administrating my AWS instance with python/boto/fabric and now want to run my app i.e.

```
sudo('python app.py &')
```

This works with standard SSH, but I want to do this via script, such that fabric (or bash script) runs this process and logs out, with the process still running. When I run this line nothing happens, although everything else, such as sudo('ls'), works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest solution is to use nohup and redirect the input and output.

```
sudo('nohup python app.py >& /dev/null < /dev/null &')
```

There are further details and instructions on the Fabric [FAQ](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/faq.html?highlight=background#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang).

Ideally, you will make your app into a daemon.